# Color detection of only object in image

Tags: python, computer-vision, color-detection

Detect color of object in image.

I have a dataset of cacti images taken from SEINET. I would like to get the color of the cacti in each image and store the name of the color. There is only one cacti per image. I am pretty new to computer vision.

I would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I tried using the YOLO model and I got a bunch of dependency errors about version mismatch for packages which is what I am trying to solve right now.

Comment: But where exactly are you stuck ?  How can the community help you exactly ?